# Content Strategy for Mobile, Desktop and Tablet

Tags: php, jquery

I'm looking for a programming solution for my content strategy problem. I have a website that is responsive and works on mobile devices and dekstop, but the content for mobile devices is different to that on a desktop.

I provide the users with free games in the gaming niche. Mobile users will want games that work on their mobile, whilst desktop users want games that work on their desktop, and it's the same for tablets.

The layout of the site is exactly the same and most of the content is similar, apart from the games that appear on the games list.

Now, I'm struggling to find a way to deal with this problematically. I'm using PHP to pull content from the database. But there is no way in PHP to tell what device a user is using (to my knowledge).

I was thinking of using jQuery to pull the content based on the device width, but then I am unsure of how this effects SEO because Google is unable to see the content.

I'm sure this a popular problem, except I can't find a solution anywhere.

Any ideas? I've listed this in jQuery and PHP as those are the languages I am using. A PHP solution would be most ideal.

Comment: [get_browser](http://php.net/manual/de/function.get-browser.php) might help you. in the output there is a platform key.

Comment: I think this is one of the things Categorizr uses. I've just been looking at it. Not sure how efficient scripts like Categorizr and WURFL are as they only state that they guess the browser.

Comment: Well the browser sends the header they use. of course you can modify this header in any browser. But most people don't do that and i think it is good enough for your problem.

Comment: From user perspective I think it's not very good to provide specific items to specific devices. What if I want to find mobile game on my desktop pc/show to friend?